# Restore column header in Windows Explorer (in "Details" mode)

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

The column headers (in Details mode) have disappeared from my Windows 7 Explorer.
(A loong time ago, so I don't remember "what I did"...)

Now I can't sort and resize directly, and that's getting *very* annoying.
**Anyone know how to show (restore) these columns headers?**

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Is this in all folders? Does this happen in all user profiles? Have you tried to reset the folder view?

Comment: @Charlie: All folders (even the ["library-folders"](http://content.screencast.com/users/martingoog/folders/Jing/media/6fdeaaaa-59fd-48e5-ae4a-297b56ace795/2011-03-25_1032.png)), but only with _my_ user account.  I've tried most setting available through the UI (context menu, folder and search options, switching between various views etc etc.).

Comment: @Charlie: Found the solution among [David's suggestions](http://superuser.com/a/543236/44259).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings sometimes get messed up by updates or other apps.
You could check to see if it's also true when viewing Photos or Music folders but more to the point, it sounds like an error in the registry.

This site [suggests a couple of fixes](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/column-headings-have-gone-in-windows-7-explorer/bdd3d53e-ee55-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5), one of which worked for some.

---

*The solution that worked in this case:*

Open the Explorer registry settings and turned off "Web View":

**Navigate to:**

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\

**And set:**

> WebView = 0x00000000 (0)

Closed all instances of Explorer and re-opened a folder (no reboot).

Comment: Thank you.  It was the "web-view" setting that messed it up in my case.